# sending an php var through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

why does this work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").click(function(){
        var table = "test";  
        $.post( "clicked.php", {tablename1:table},function( data ) {
              $( ".result" ).html( data );
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

but this doesnt?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").click(function(){
        var table = <?php echo $tablename; ?>;  
        $.post( "clicked.php", {tablename1:table},function( data ) {
              $( ".result" ).html( data );
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Isnt this the way to send a php var through ajax ??

Comment: Try to change `var table = <?php echo $tablename; ?>; ` to `var table = "<?php echo json_encode($tablename); ?>"; `. Make sure the javascript is called _after_ the PHP variable is set or changed. That being said, there is probably a better way for you to do this.

Comment: Where are your double quotes ? For the second instance? Try Putting your php variable in json format

Comment: <?php echo $tablename; ?>; gives as result (in your case): test and the assignment var table = test considering test as a js variable. You need to double quote the result echoed from php so the result must be: "test".

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks . it worked

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript strings need to be enclosed in quotes ("string"). The code `var table = <?php echo $tablename; ?>;` will result in (assuming tablename is equal to foobar) - `var table = foobar`, which is a string not enclosed in quotes. I hope that you see where this is going...

Try this as your solution:

```
var table = "<?php echo $tablename; ?>";
```

Comment: Better IMHO to use `echo json_encode($tablename);`. `json_encode()` will add the quotes, as well as escape characters if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you're missing the quotes around the value.

You should use `json_encode()` to translate a PHP value to the corresponding JavaScript literal syntax.

```
var table = <?php echo json_encode($tablename); ?>;
```

In addition to quoting the string, it will also escape it if necessary. This method can be used for most types of values.